# Definition of a View Table like students prevents operation UPDATE on person table

Tags: mysql, sql

## students as view which is related To person Table

```
UPDATE persons 
SET persons.EN_FAMILY = 'Test' 
WHERE persons.STCODE IN
        (SELECT students.PERSONS_STCODE AS STCODE 
         FROM students 
         WHERE @Counter > 0 
         AND students.ID NOT IN
            (SELECT sel_lesson.ST_ID 
             FROM sel_lesson 
             WHERE sel_lesson.YEAR = @CurrenYear 
             AND sel_lesson.TERM = @CurrentTerm 
             GROUP BY sel_lesson.ST_ID)
         AND students.STATUS IN('1','14')
);
```

Comment: Is it Oracle or MySQL? And what is the issue? Are you having an error? Which one? Also, say I want to help you, I would need to reproduce the error, but I don't know the structure of involved tables and views, so I can not even try to run this statement. Please edit your question by building a [mcve]

Comment: Is MySQL, the sub query work success and return 3 row but In update not work

Comment: So, again, how can I reproduce the error and try to help you? And what does "not work" mean? Does it give an error? Or does it do something unexpected?

Comment: Is there actually a view in this query and if so what is it called?

Comment: Error Log Is = > Definition of Table `students` prevents operation UPDATE on table `person`

Comment: @Nick Sub query Is work But Update Not work

Comment: @P.Salmon Status Field Is required for query And Not exist In person Is In The view

Comment: @ali a view has a very specific meaning in sql. You will have a better chance of getting an answer if you publish all your table specifications (and views if there are any) together with sample data as text to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try use an inner join

```
UPDATE persons 
INNER JOIN  (SELECT students.PERSONS_STCODE AS STCODE 
         FROM students 
         WHERE @Counter > 0 
         AND students.ID NOT IN
            (SELECT sel_lesson.ST_ID 
             FROM sel_lesson 
             WHERE sel_lesson.YEAR = @CurrenYear 
             AND sel_lesson.TERM = @CurrentTerm 
             GROUP BY sel_lesson.ST_ID)
         AND students.STATUS IN('1','14') ) T on t.STCODE = persons.STCODE

SET persons.EN_FAMILY = 'Test'
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience,but this query Has Error Like My query

Comment: @ali  show me your exact error message ..

Comment: answay  .. added  a  mssing )  before T on